# unable to change date format - R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

The date is currently yyyy-mm-dd, but I want it as mm/dd/yyyy.

I've tried various methods which either result in absolutely nothing happening or getting errors such as:

Warning message:
Problem while computing `date = lubridate::mdy(date)`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `date = format(date, "%m/%d/%Y")`.
Caused by error in `format.default()`:
! invalid 'trim' argument
Backtrace:

1. mass %>% mutate(date = format(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
2. base::format.default(date, "%m/%d/%Y")

How do I fix this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mass = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/mass_killing_incidents_public.csv')

mass2 = mass
mass2$date = format(mass$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

mass2 = mass %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(date),
         date = strftime(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))

mass2 = mass %>% 
  mutate(date = format(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: I think the original data is `ymd` format i.e. `mass %>%mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date),
         date = strftime(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))`

Comment: Aha! That did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mass %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date), date = strftime(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```